# PhpStorm: How to change project's subversion instance?

Tags: php, svn, amazon-web-services, ide, phpstorm

I'm using the PhpStorm IDE to write a PHP project.  I've connected to a free tier Amazon AWS instance where I installed subversion, created a repository, synced up my PhpStorm project to it, then deleted the repository (due to some issues I was having and hoping for a clean slate).

I'd like to be able to commit my project to the new SVN repository (which I successfully imported the existing code into), but I simply cannot find a way, in PhpStorm, to change the subversion instance tied to my project to the new repository.  Currently, when I try to commit, I get the "repository UUIDs do not match" error message.  Attempting a "relocate working copy" gives me the similar message about UUIDs.

So my question is: **how do I change my current project to commit to a NEW subversion repository?**

I've reached out to the PhpStorm support staff as well, but thus far they have done nothing but run me in circles, which brings me here instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple: close PHPStorm and delete vcs.xml file from .idea folder

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into a similar problem. Cleaning up the project solved it for me. Follow the following steps and it will solve out the problem for you:

Step 1: Make a copy of your code, excluding the .idea and .svn (hidden) folders.
Step 2: Close your IDE
Step 3: Delete the project folder along with .idea and .svn folders.
Step 4: Make a new fresh project folder, copy back the source code into your project folder
Step 5: Start your IDE and select Open and then select the new project folder
Step 6: Now share your project on the new repository location and then you can start working again.

Hope it helps!